# How do I implement a virtualization app like virtualbox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

There are many tutorials on how to create a virtual machine using platforms like vmware, virtualbox, hyper-v, etc.

But how do these apps actually work?

And how would one go about implementing software that can create virtual machines?

Comment: What do you want exactly? To develop an app which is a virtual machine, or to develop a new virtualization engine, or what?

Comment: I would like to understand how to go about developing a virtualization engine.